# Saving an image using getExternalStoragePublicDirectory

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, mediastore

I am attempting to write an Android application that will allow a user to capture an image. The user would press the "Capture" button when they are ready to take the image, the camera will open up for them to take a picture, and then the photo would be saved to `DCIM\testdir`.

So far I am able to get the camera to open up and take a picture, but after taking the picture, I am unable to get it to save properly (see picture): http://i.imgur.com/4IkFowo.png

I am able to click the cancel button to take me back to my app and I can also hit the refresh button to take another picture, but pressing the check button does not do anything. I would like for it to save the photo to the directory that I specified and take me back to my app.

Here is my source code:

```
import java.io.File;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;

public class ContactSelected extends Activity {
    private Uri fileUri;
    private static final int CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE = 100;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_contact_selected);

        Button cameraButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bLaunchCamera); 
        cameraButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // Do something when a list item is clicked

                // Create Intent to take a picture and return control to the calling application
                Intent camera = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
                File imagesFolder = new File(Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DCIM), "testdir");
                imagesFolder.mkdirs();
                imagesFolder.setWritable(true);
                File image = new File(imagesFolder, "image_001.jpg");
                fileUri = Uri.fromFile(image);
                camera.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, fileUri);  // set the image file name

                // Start the image capture Intent
                startActivityForResult(camera, CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE);
            }

            public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
                if (requestCode == CAPTURE_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE) {
                    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                        finish();
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.contact_selected, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```